# Could anyone try to debunk this claim?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy

I recently came across this Jain claim which says **“If God is ever perfect and complete, how could the will to create have arisen in him? If, on the other hand, he is not perfect, he could no more create the universe than a potter could”**. Could anyone try to ‘debunk’ this claim?

Comment: As another point, you said '*the will to create arise*'  , can a will arise in God? Isn't he all knowing In the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the average understanding of what perfection is. Perfection is really a human attribute, this is how we understand it. The attributes of Allah are beyond all classifications - this is what perfection means here - but nevertheless, because of what we and who we are, that is given our rational faculty we tend to look for rationalisations of the attributes. This discipline is known in Islam as *kalam*.

The Sufi Mystics eschewed such rationalisations and attempted to seek the inner sense of divine reality; in the same way, if we see an outward light, we may seek the source of it. In a sense, they were reifying faith.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>[Iklhas: 2](https://quran.com/112/2)</sub>

> ***الله الصمد***
>
> God is free of any need.

He is not perfected by his actions. We are. I'm perfected if I have a house. I have more kids. I have the best job in town.

It's only through his blessing and bounty that we exist. Not through his need for perfection.

The only thing is that if God didn't create us or have the will to do such, then we wouldn't know. But us not knowing about the traits of something doesn't invalidate the traits of that thing. You have $100trillion in your bank account and no one on the planet knows that you're the richest person. Does that mean you're not the richest person?

In fact if he was forced to show his perfection by doing something, then he wouldn't be perfect, rather be in need of something *else*

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest problems when people try to argue on matters like these is Allah is out of the reach of anyone's minds and people try to argue on this topic with their little minds and knowledge that He gave them. They try to perceive and judge based on imperfect scales they have set themselves.

Thus as the other brother pointed out, What does "perfection" really mean when somebody makes this claim. No one knows what it means because no one is perfect. How can our imperfect minds ever conceive the notion or concept of perfection. Whatever we have in our minds about perfection is our own conjured up image based on a variety of different things.

All we should know and believe to save our Imaan are the basic foundations or beliefs i.e. Allah is free from any sort of weaknesses and what some of his abilities/attributes are. If there ever was a perfect answer to questions like these, people wouldn't struggle in the first place to admit the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Brother allah[sub] is free of everything he like a computer scientist who can do anything as he wishes to he is a artist who can paint anything in his canvas .so to understand this we need some example

1. he is the perfect so his will of creating us is a honour  and luck for us  and it is irrelevant to question on his  will to create us and suppose you have  $1 billion in your account  and anyone dose not knows about it then it dose not  means that you dont have billion dollar in account and if you try to earn more it dose not means you are not satisfied with your wealth indeed it dose not means you are not billionare or you are unsatisfied